Можно ли в python добавить знак ∞ в класс 'int', или создать новый класс и туда добавить?
Нужно, чтобы при создании функции можно было вводить знак бесконечности без строчных кавычек (return ∞ ), чтоб он был числом.

Но зачем? . . .

Добавить в int нельзя. Создать свой класс можно.

@StanislavVolodarskiy но return ∞ это синтаксическая ошибка в любом случае

@andreymal, код - личное дело программиста. Будет (MyInt.INFINITY) - это ничего не меняет.

@StanislavVolodarskiy требование «вводить знак бесконечности без строчных кавычек» прописано в вопросе вполне чётко, чьи-либо личные дела не имеют тут никакого значения (за исключением самого главного вопроса «***** а главное зачем»)

@andreymal, "вводить" и return не бьются. Я прочитал "вводить" как возможность ввода пользователем из файла/входного потока/строки, а return проигнорировал.

"...return ∞ ), чтоб он был числом..." - ОН не будет числом! Разберитесь с определениями элементарной математики. Это бесконечность. Есть такое: положительная бесконечность: positive_infinity = float('inf') и такое: отрицательная бесконечность: negative_infinity = float('-inf')
